# LOESS and MA normalization in R?

Tags: r, regression, normalization, loess

Attempting to do loess on two variables `x` and `y` in R using MA normalization(see [MA-plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot); see also [Bland-Altman or Tukey mean-difference plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey_mean-difference_plot)) like this:

```
> x = rnorm(100) + 5
> y = x + 0.6 + rnorm(100)*0.8
> m = log(x/y)
> a = 0.5*log(x*y)
```

I want to normalize x and y in such a way that the average `m` is 0, as in standard MA normalization, and then back-calculate the correct x and y values. First running loess on MA:

```
> l = loess(m ~ a)
```

What is the way to get corrected `m` values then? Is this correct?

```
> mc <- predict(l, a)
# original MA plot
> plot(a,m)
# corrected MA plot
> plot(a,m-mc)
```

not clear to me what `predict` actually does in the case of `loess` objects and how it's different from using `l$residuals` in the object `l` returned by `loess` - can someone explain?
finally, how can I back calculate new `x` and `y` values based on this correction?

Attempt to back-calculate `x` and `y`: the corrected `m` is,

```
new_m = m - mc
```

so `x,y` can be derived from the definition of `m`:

```
m = log(x/y) = log(x) - log(y)
```

therefore,

```
x = exp(new_m + log(y))
y = exp(-1*(new_m - log(x)))
```

but this is wrong; there's a missing scaling factor of a half and I'd like to see a derivation of where that comes from. Probably from the definition of `A` but I don't see why I can't get the same be rewriting `x,y` in terms of `A`

**edit** if someone can explain where the half correction factor comes in when back calculating `x` -- i.e. why the formula `x = exp(new_m + log(y))` is wrong -- i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Generally, if I see the abbreviation "MA", I would expect [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) is being discussed. Could you explain (in your question) what MA stands for the first time you mention it, please?

Comment: @Gleb_b: sorry for confusion, stands for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of it before. Sounds a lot like a *[Tukey mean-difference plot](http://www.statistics.com/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=364)* (/sum-difference plot).

Comment: Please do not [cross post on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534287/how-to-do-ma-and-loess-normalization-in-r)

Comment: @mnel: did not know which was the right place it seems equally relevant

Comment: Better to post in one only -- if it is off topic in one, it will be closed and migrated to the other.

Comment: @Glen_b: The MA-plot is an application of a Bland–Altman plot for visual representation of microarray gene expression data. The Bland-Altman plot is known as Tukey's mean-difference plot in other fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all try and be consistent with logs (choose either `log` or `log2` but not both with your `m` and `a` calculations)

The steps that you have outlined do look correct. `predict()` will take a model (generated by `loess(m ~ a)`) and give you the 'corrected' `m` (`mc`) for every value `a`. You can view the loess line by doing

```
#set.seed(12345)
x = rnorm(100) + 5
y = x + 0.6 + rnorm(100)*0.8

m = log(x/y)
a = 0.5*log(x*y)

l = loess(m ~ a) 
mc <- predict(l, a)

plot(a, m, ylim=c(-0.5, 0.5)); 
#make sure things are ordered for the lines() plot
lines(a[order(m)], mc[order(m)]) #this is the loess line through the points m
dev.new()

#if you want your m centered around loess line
plot(a, m-mc, ylim=c(-0.5, 0.5)); dev.new()

#rescaled values
x2 = exp(log(x) - mc/2)
y2 = exp(log(y) + mc/2)
m2 = log(x2/y2)
a2 = 0.5*log(x2*y2)

plot(a2, m2, ylim=c(-0.5, 0.5)) #same as second plot
```

In this case, `l$residual` and `m-mc` are the same values because you are interested in predicting everything that you fit. However, you could do `mc2 = predict(l, a2)` where a2 might be a superset or something else you want to fit a similar transform to, `m2-mc2` will be different from `l$residual`. This is useful if you are only interested in using a subset of your data to fit to the model but interested in adjusting all of your data.

Also see this loess guide [here](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Statistics/loess.htm)

As for the back calculation, I think you just adjust X and Y by mc

```
x2 = exp(log(x) - mc/2)
y2 = exp(log(y) + mc/2)
```

If you are working on gene expression, the [affy package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/affy.html) has all of this implemented under `normalize.loess()`

Comment: thank you! final question: can you explain the difference between `m+predict(l,a)` and `m+l$residuals`? shouldn't the corrected `m` just be `m` plus its residuals?

Comment: I tried to explain this in the 3rd paragraph. The residual is the distance from the point to the model. When you run loess command with `m` and `a`, the `l$residual` will be the distance between `m` and the model. When you are predicting `a`, what the function will give back is: Given a model `l` and these points `a`, how much would I adjust to get to the line from model. 

Maybe its easier to think of it this way, if your `a` was always integers and you wanted to predict 5.5, you aren't going to find 5.5 in your `a` but you can figure it out using the model.

Comment: ok so just to make it explicit could you say what the notation would be for expressing the corrected m value as a function of `predict`'s output? is it: `new_m = g(a) + error`?

Comment: I think I am confusing myself and confusing you, the best thing to look at is to plot the `lines(a, mc)` in in my answer and I hope that will make things easier to see.

Comment: it all pretty much makes sense except getting the scaling back to `x` and `y` both corrected. there's some sort of `0.5` scaling factor that I am missing. I don't think the above definition of `X_rescale` and `Y_rescale` is correct.

Comment: also i think you meant `lines(mc)` not `lines(a,mc)`?

Comment: I see you added the 0.5 but where does it come from? if you go by the definition of `M = log(X/Y)` then you can derive `X = ..., Y = ...` without a half, right?

Comment: you are right about the rescaling, you shift both x and y closer together (decreasing their fold change). The amount of shift by is stored in `mc`. Since you are shifting both X and Y you shift each by half of `mc`. The `lines` command is correct, loess is not a straight line, see the guide I linked.

Comment: I still don't see why it's a half scaling factor

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8006/discussion-between-yingw-and-user248237)

Answer (score 1):

yingw's answer is good and mostly correct - there is a minor mistake in the code, though. To correctly plot the loess curve, line 13 should read like the following (ordered by a rather than m):

```
lines(a[order(a)], mc[order(a)]) #this is the loess line through the points m
```

[image]

Sorry I didn't post this as a comment - not enought reputation, yet...